# CSS fixed top menu navigation is under some items

Tags: html, css

I encountered a problem regarded my website:
I tried to make the upper menu fixed and now when I'm scrolling through the website, all the headings and paragraphs are over the menu:

Here's a picture of the problem
[image]

This is the HTML for the fixed top menu

```
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
        <a href="#" class="active">Home</a>
        <a href="#">About</a>
        <a href="#">Menu1</a>
        <a href="#">Menu2</a>
    </div>
```

This is the CSS for the fixed top menu

```
.topnav {
background-color: #333;
overflow: hidden;
position: fixed; /* Set the navbar to fixed position */
top: 0; /* Position the navbar at the top of the page */
width: 100%; /* Full width */
}
```

So the question would be: How can I make it to be on top of everything?

Comment: Could be a `z-index` set somewhere. Please provide a minimal example on https://jsfiddle.net/.

Comment: That was the problem. I didn't found on the items that were above the nav-menu any z-index set. I solved it anyway, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.topnav {
    background-color: #333;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 100; /* or 999 */
    position: fixed; /* Set the navbar to fixed position */
    top: 0; /* Position the navbar at the top of the page */
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Setting The 'z-index' to a higher value